# Is there a way to pass variable into jQ .attr or .css?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to pass variables as  `.attr` or `.css` value?
For example

```
containerHeight = $('#div1").height();
$('#div2').css('height',containerHeight)
```

Comment: Yes there is, and what you have will work fine when you fix the mis-matched quotes. I'd strongly suggest you use a IDE with syntax highlighting as it makes it next to impossible to miss errors like this. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: it will work.what problem you are facing?

Comment: @Anant Please don't edit questions to fix typos. If there is an error in the question's code raise it as a comment and let the OP confirm if it was a mistake in the question only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is the quotes that you have used wrongly. See the below snippet

```js
$(function(){
   var containerHeight = $("#div1").height();
   console.log(containerHeight);
$('#div2').css('height',containerHeight)
})
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Hello</div>
<div id="div2">World</div>
```